# Traefik ACME DNS-01 gcloud duplicate records

Tags: dns, gcloud, lets-encrypt, traefik

I'm not sure if this is an issue specific to traefik and my config or a bug but moving my provider from route53 to gcloud my acme configuration generates 409 duplicate resource errors from google.

It appears like the acme code is expecting to be able to override TXT records but can't on gcloud.

The errors look like:

```
time="2018-11-01T11:46:41Z" level=error msg="Error obtaining certificate: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[qa.mydomain.com] error presenting token: googlecloud: googleapi: Error 409: The resource 'entity.change.additions[0].rrdata[1]' named '\"VuOLZS3tfLfrOswFtV3mayqOYaz5PvQK16nJdgMdMez\"' already exists, alreadyExists\n"
time="2018-11-01T11:46:41Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"*.qa.mydomain.com,qa.mydomain.com\" : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [*.qa.mydomain.com qa.mydomain.com]: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[qa.mydomain.com] error presenting token: googlecloud: googleapi: Error 409: The resource 'entity.change.additions[0].rrdata[1]' named '\"VuOLZS3tfLfrOswFtV3mayqOYaz5PvQK16nJdgMdMez\"' already exists, alreadyExists\n"
time="2018-11-01T11:46:41Z" level=error msg="Error obtaining certificate: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[development.mydomain.com] error presenting token: googlecloud: googleapi: Error 409: The resource 'entity.change.additions[0].rrdata[1]' named '\"Jfv6orVfbwi0IdQbmpvG3qnIltMX5x56vGUpHjoBzOa\"' already exists, alreadyExists\n"
time="2018-11-01T11:46:41Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"*.development.mydomain.com,development.mydomain.com\" : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [*.development.mydomain.com development.mydomain.com]: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[development.mydomain.com] error presenting token: googlecloud: googleapi: Error 409: The resource 'entity.change.additions[0].rrdata[1]' named '\"Jfv6orVfbwi0IdQbmpvG3qnIltMX5x56vGUpHjoBzOa\"' already exists, alreadyExists\n"
```

The acme configuration:

```
[acme]
  email = "email@mydomain.com"
  storage = "/acme-certificates/acme.json"
  acmeLogging = true
  entryPoint = "https"

[acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "gcloud"

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.development.mydomain.com"
  sans = ["development.mydomain.com"]

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.qa.mydomain.com"
  sans = ["qa.mydomain.com"]
```

Comment: I could find a closed GitHub [issue](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4149) with a solution. Are you still facing the issue, or did the GitHub solution worked? 
I would recommend posting DNS or System Administration related questions in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) as StackOverflow is for Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logged as traefik [bug](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4149), patched and closed.

Answer (score 0):

That's the error you get when you have a bare domain and a wildcard domain on the same record - because it tries to add two TXT records, which most DNS providers support.

However, google requires you to delete the record and then add a new record with two rrdata fields instead of two separate records.

:-/

It's a bug. Google DNS is **NOT** easy to program for.

Comment: I logged it as a traefik [bug](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4149). It was patched and closed and I forgot about the SO post, sorry.